# Laravel prevent database access for a specific route

Tags: php, session, laravel, laravel-4

I've got a route `/status` that is used by my load balancer to determine if my instance is up and running. I need this to be controlled by laravel (as opposed to apache) so I can leverage the `artisan down/up` commands to manually control instance health.

I had an incident today where my database was rejecting connections (an unrelated issue). Unfortunately, this caused the `/status` route to fail because it was connecting to the database (for sessions). I've added a filter to use the array session driver in the hope that it would stop accessing the database but for some reason it's still hitting the db.

Here's my route with the filter. It's all very simple:

```
Route::filter('disablesessions', function() {
  Config::set('session.driver', 'array');
});
Route::get('/status', ['before' => 'disablesessions', function() {
  return 'ok';
}]);
```

When I `curl -v http://localhost/status` I get the following response (no cookies, yay!):

```
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Date: Tue, 02 Sep 2014 19:48:45 GMT
* Server Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu) is not blacklisted
< Server: Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu)
< X-Powered-By: PHP/5.5.9-1ubuntu4.3
< Cache-Control: no-cache
< Vary: Accept-Encoding
< Transfer-Encoding: chunked
< Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
```

As a test, I changed my database password in `config/database.php` to something incorrect. My hope is that because the route isn't hitting the database at all, it shouldn't care that the password is incorrect. Wrong! The route failed. Worse, the stack trace indicated that the connection was initiated due to a sessions-related codepath.

[image: Stack Trace]

This seems really bizarre to me. My first hunch is that there's a sessions-related code path in the framework that happens before the `disablesessions` filter runs which causes the connection to happen. The filter runs afterwards and affects the response (no cookie). I'd really appreciate some help here :)

Comment: I don't know if you can remove database interacting completely. Honestly if you are not serving an application from this instance then a full-stack framework like Laravel is probably the wrong tool.

Comment: @rich97 we're leveraging the database for 99% of our other routes for which Laravel is a great choice. We need this one specific route to be database independent so that database issues don't disrupt our php servers.

Answer (score 3):

I could be wrong. There may be a way to disable database access completely for a route but looking at the stack trace it seems as though the connection is established deeply in the code and my Googling is returning nothing.

You could also switch the connection to use SQLite, you don't need a server to run SQLite as it's stored as a file on the file system. So set up an SQL config and make sure it's writeable and replace your filter with:

```
Config::set('database.default', 'sqlite');
```

The alternative is you use a rewrite rule and let Apache/Nginx handle that route. Just circumvent Laravel completely and point it to a script of your choosing. This also has the small advantage that if something goes wrong with your application then the status script is unaffected.

Comment: Thanks @rich97! I'm leaning towards pure Apache right now. Appreciate it.

Comment: Glad I could help. Would you mind marking as answered so that I can get those sweet, sweet imaginary Internet points?